# Insert pdf pages with choice of which pages of original doc

Tags: pdfpages

To insert only a few pages of a PDF document to my latex document, I use this macro. The numbering of the pages in my document is not interrupted even if I customize the header-footer with fancyheader.

```
\documentclass{article}
%%%% www.madit.be
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
    \geometry{top=25mm,bottom=25mm,inner=25mm,outer=20mm,,marginparwidth=1cm,marginparsep=10pt}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% macro
\newcounter{myCurrentPage}
\newcounter{myLastPage}
\newcommand{\myMultipdf}[3]{%args: {uri of pdf}{startpage}{endpage}
    \setcounter{myCurrentPage}{\number#2}%page start
    \setcounter{myLastPage}{(\number#3)+1}%last page    
    \whiledo{\themyCurrentPage<\themyLastPage}{%
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,page=\value{myCurrentPage}]{#1}
        \newpage
        \setcounter{myCurrentPage}{\value{myCurrentPage}+1}
    }%
}
\begin{document}

\section{Some Text}

\lipsum[1]

\section{Some insert of pdf pages}

\myMultipdf{foo.pdf}{3}{4}

\section{Some Text}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course to use this example correctly, you must replace the foo.pdf by (1) a correct URI and (2) with the actual name of your document.

Comment: However i have 1 BadBox at compile :
Overfull \hbox(15.0pt too wide). Who has an idea to avoid this?

Comment: I'm having trouble finding the question in your question. If your question is how to avoid the BadBox I believe you should update the question with that.

Comment: @ Silex. No my first objective was'nt to ask something. Simply add small piece of code to the community. Early as newbies, I lost a lot of time to find an easy way to insert often PDF pages in a large syllabus. It is only sharing. But it is true that the most talented of you will find it a bit "light" ;-)

Comment: In that case you should formulate a question and add your solution as an answer.

Comment: OK, it was not an question and it is also the last time I try to share any experience on this forum! Apparently it is only for questions and not for sharing :-( It's dommage, because this forum is a very good source of stuff and tricks for beginners Latex (like me). (translate from french with google).

Comment: @madit: Sharing knowledge is fine, it's even encouraged! You just have to play hide-and-seek a bit, i.e. you have to ask a question that can be answered with the knowledge you have. (See [Asking a question and answering it yourself straight away](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4)) The question needs to meet the same quality standards as any other question. I'd encourage you to [edit] your question in such a way; I'm sure there would not be a problem reopening it once it is a real question.

Answer (score 5):

The overfull `\hbox` is caused by `\parindent`. The graphics starts a new paragraph and the width is the line width. `\noindent` suppresses the paragraph indent:

```
\noindent
\includegraphics...
```

For completeness. Also

```
\includepdf[pages=3-4,pagecommand={}]{foo.pdf}
```

keeps the head and foot lines of the original document. But the original document might contribute it own head and foot lines. The margins can be influenced to some degree by options `trim`, `clip`.

Comment: Indeed, the command `\noindent` suppresses bad box. Thanks for this tip.

But I do not like the command "includepdf" because it causes a page break before insertion.

With the following command, it is possible to insert a section on the same page, but unfortunately it is repeated on every page :-(.

`\includepdf [pages = 3-4, scale = 0.9, pagecommand = {\section {With includepdf}} ] {} foo.pdf`

And as includepdf documentation is very basic, so I ended up using this macro.